# Easiest way to go to your previous location in a large word document

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-word-2003

I make regular small edits to a 150 page document and find it frustrating that word does not remember what part of the document I last edited. Is there some option I can set in word so that it does remember, or if not, can someone suggest an easy trick to help with this problem.

**EDIT:** The document is divided into a great many chapters and sub-sections and sub-sub-sections. Any tips on quickly jumping around from section to section would go a long way to helping with my problem. In outlining mode, with all the outlines closed, jumping around the file is a joy... but very irritatingly, when word is shut down and re-started, it opens all the outlines. So at the moment, at the beginning of every editing session I manually close all the outlines, then I can more easily navigate to the part I want to edit. This feels very clumsy, especially if all I want to do is add one sentence somewhere.

Comment: Sounds like bookmarks could help you here.

Comment: What, no vi fanboys wanted to jump in? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question... I've just discovered that I can close all the outlines in one shot by clicking "Show Level 1". This means I can jump to whatever section I like pretty quickly. Using a bookmark as suggested by "random" is useful too.

Comment: If your sections are named something unique (like Chapter 1, 2, etc...), you can search for that section, Ctrl + F.

Answer (score 0):

*During* an editing session:

```
Undo then Redo.
```

At the *start* of an editing session:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>

Note the latter may require [an edit to Normal.dot](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/apperrors/gobackfix.htm).

Comment: @hugh allen: sounds like a genius idea.. but upon starting word, undo and redo are greyed out :-(

Comment: @Mick: No, it only works within an editing session, not after loading a saved document :(